# Enabling login page for spring Authorization/Resource server

Tags: spring-security, kotlin, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to get OAuth2 based SSO working with spring. I've created a server and client, but I've run into an issue where after enabling the Authorization and Resource server.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
open class GsAuthenticationApplication {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            SpringApplication.run(GsAuthenticationApplication::class.java, *args)
        }

    }
}
```

Once that's all wired up, the generated /login page is no longer available, as it seems to be treated as an protected OAuth resource

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

I created a WebSecurityCOnfigurerAdapter bean, and tried to explicitly set it up with the configure method below, but it's still giving me the same issue

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        //super.configure(http)
        // @formatter:off
        http
            ?.authorizeRequests()
            ?.and()
            ?.formLogin()
                ?.loginPage("/login")
                ?.permitAll()
        // @formatter:on

    }
```

Comment: one side note, on the overridden `configure` function you can change the nullability to just `HttpSecurity` if you know this function never really receives a null and it is still a valid override.  Will allow you to remove all the `?` null safety.

Comment: Yeah, I'd actually gotten around to fixing that.  The ? was added when I used the 'generate override..'

Comment: @ErichOliphant, did you find solution? =)